# Powershell 5.# add type accelerator and use in class in same file

Tags: powershell, type-accelerators

I have been running into trouble adding new type accelerators in PS 5.1. I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31895.adding-type-accelerators-in-the-powershell-5-0-april-2015-preview.aspx), and a few other similar references, so my understanding is that this is the case for all 5.# builds of PowerShell, not just the referenced preview. To that end, I have this

```
CLS
$accelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$accelerators::Add("pxList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]])
$accelerators::Add("pxHashList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]])
$builtinTypeAccelerators = $accelerators.GetField("builtinTypeAccelerators", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]"Static,NonPublic")
$builtinTypeAccelerators.SetValue($builtinTypeAccelerators, $accelerators::Get)

class pxT_DefinitionsMigrater {
    # Properties
    $XML = [xml.xmlDocument]::new()
    $Errors = [pxList]::new()
    $initiations = [pxHashList]::new()

    # Constructor
    pxT_DefinitionsMigrater ([string]$xmlPath) {
    }
}

[pxT_DefinitionsMigrater]::new('String')
```

And I am still getting `Unable to find type` errors. Where am I going wrong? Interestingly, this DOES work.

```
CLS
$accelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$accelerators::Add("pxList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]])
$accelerators::Add("pxHashList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]])
$builtinTypeAccelerators = $accelerators.GetField("builtinTypeAccelerators", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]"Static,NonPublic")
$builtinTypeAccelerators.SetValue($builtinTypeAccelerators, $accelerators::Get)

([pxHashList]::new()).GetType().FullName
```

It seems that custom type accelerators don't work (the same way) with classes. So perhaps more importantly, is adding our own type accelerators still considered good practice, or is this change since PS5 an indication that we really shouldn't be doing it? Or at least not doing it in conjunction with classes?

Also, as an aside, but something that certainly doesn't warrant an actual question, I notice that the `new` method is not capitalized. When I get my intellisence options in the ISE for my new type `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals` are both capitalized, but `new` isn't. This is true for every `new` I have seen. Seems like there must be some useful information packaged in that fact.

EDIT: Very interesting discovery, just after my initial post.
This also works

```
CLS
$accelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$accelerators::Add("pxList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]])
$accelerators::Add("pxHashList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]])
$builtinTypeAccelerators = $accelerators.GetField("builtinTypeAccelerators", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]"Static,NonPublic")
$builtinTypeAccelerators.SetValue($builtinTypeAccelerators, $accelerators::Get)

class pxT_DefinitionsMigrater {
    # Properties
    $XML = [xml.xmlDocument]::new()
    $Errors = $null
    $initiations = $null

    # Constructor
    pxT_DefinitionsMigrater ([string]$xmlPath) {
        $this.Errors = [pxList]::new()
        $this.initiations = [pxHashList]::new()
    }
}

[pxT_DefinitionsMigrater]::new('String')
```

So, the XML property can be assigned an actual value in the properties section, of an empty `[xml.document]`, but I can't create new empty versions of my new types there, I need to do it in the ctor. Makes me wonder if there is an argument for always setting properties to `$null` at declaration, and then assigning a value in the constructor. So...

```
CLS
$accelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$accelerators::Add("pxList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]])
$accelerators::Add("pxHashList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]])
$builtinTypeAccelerators = $accelerators.GetField("builtinTypeAccelerators", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]"Static,NonPublic")
$builtinTypeAccelerators.SetValue($builtinTypeAccelerators, $accelerators::Get)

class pxT_DefinitionsMigrater {
    # Properties
    [xml.xmlDocument]$XML = $null
    [pxList]$Errors = $null
    [pxHashList]$initiations = $null

    # Constructor
    pxT_DefinitionsMigrater ([string]$xmlPath) {
        $this.XML = [xml.xmlDocument]::new()
        $this.Errors = [pxList]::new()
        $this.initiations = [pxHashList]::new()
    }
}

[pxT_DefinitionsMigrater]::new('String')
```

If you have a number of ctor variations this seems a bit wasteful, but perhaps is best practice?

EDIT: Indeed, it seems it is second run that allows things to work, not where the accelerator is used. Given that this will eventually be a script and not run in the ISE, an answer that works in both places would be ideal.

```
$accelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$accelerators::Add("pxList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]])
$accelerators::Add("pxHashList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]])
$builtinTypeAccelerators = $accelerators.GetField("builtinTypeAccelerators", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]"Static,NonPublic")
$builtinTypeAccelerators.SetValue($builtinTypeAccelerators, $accelerators::Get)

class pxT_DefinitionsMigrater {
    # Properties
    [xml.xmlDocument]$XML
    [pxList]$Errors
    [pxHashList]$initiations

    # Constructor
    [Void]initializeProperties () {
        $this.XML = [xml.xmlDocument]::new()
        $this.Errors = [pxList]::new()
        $this.initiations = [pxHashList]::new()
    }
    pxT_DefinitionsMigrater ([string]$xmlPath) {
        $this.initializeProperties()
    }
}

[pxT_DefinitionsMigrater]::new('String')
```

Comment: Hmmm, Another thing. Looks like your very first example work if you do it in two times. Meaning if you select the custom accelerators then F8 and then you load the remaining stuff (class definition + new object)

Answer (score 1):

A Powershell Code containing class definitions first evaluates them.

```bsh
# works!
[myClass]::new()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
class myClass{}          # this line runs first
```

```bsh
# throws!
f               # this line runs first
function f {}

f: The term 'f' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ...
```

The problem is that
the class `pxT_DefinitionsMigrater` is try to use a type that's not defined yet.

The solution is

1. Define types and classes in separate files.
2. Load a type definitions file first, then class definitions.

---

Update

It's possible to define types and classes in a single file base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35220091/13388552)

```bsh
function GetPxLists {
    if (("pxList" -as [type]) -eq $null){
        $accelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
        $accelerators::Add("pxList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]])
        $accelerators::Add("pxHashList",[System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]])
        $builtinTypeAccelerators = $accelerators.GetField("builtinTypeAccelerators", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]"Static,NonPublic")
        $builtinTypeAccelerators.SetValue($builtinTypeAccelerators, $accelerators::Get)
    }

    [pxList]::new(), [pxHashList]::new()
}


# and inside class
    # Constructor
    pxT_DefinitionsMigrater ([string]$xmlPath) {
        $PxLists = GetPxLists
        $this.Errors = $PxLists[0]
        $this.initiations = $PxLists[1]
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, in that it seems to make it impossible to have a self contained module with classes and type accelerators, which seems like a common thing to do. But, this is Microsoft, and so I guess I have to choose classes OR accelerators, and I'll take classes. Accelerators are a convenience, classes solve the polluted pipeline problem amongst other things, and that alone is worth loosing custom accelerators :-)
Still, would like to see MS get this right. We shouldn't have to choose either or.

Comment: found a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35220091/13388552.
@Gordon, Can you make the question as 'a duplicate' (without flagged by someone)?

Comment: That's an interesting tangent. A quick look shows that solution working for methods, whereas I was at least trying to use the custom type accelerator in a property default value. But, the bit about compilation does help me understand a little bit. The classes aren't just loading, they have to compile so they can be used, then execution starts from the first line. In any case, now to see if I can actually make this work as a default value for a property. If I can, I'll flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: IMO You don't have to choose. Module can very well be self-contained. The module can consist of more than just the psm1/psd1 files. Accelerators and classes can be located in 2 additionals  data file included in the module and be loaded first thing in the psm1.  Actually, you can probably use the `ScriptsToProcess` PSD1 element to load these extra files sequentially and they will be included automatically in the published module.

Comment: @sage-pourpre Looks like I have some research to do. the only module I am familiar with is a PSM1 file. And loading classes from a PSM1 is already a bit weird. But, off to read about manifests. :)