# Unable to find type [CloudFileDirectory] error - dependent assemblies in a custom Azure DSC module

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

I have created a custom module as a PowerShell class following, roughly, the instructions available at [Writing a custom DSC resource with PowerShell classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/authoringresourceclass).  The intent is to connect to Azure File Storage and download some files. I am using Azure Automation DSC as my pull server.

Let me start by saying that, when run through the PowerShell ISE, the code works a treat.  Something goes wrong when I upload it to Azure though - I get the error `Unable to find type [CloudFileDirectory]`.  This type specifier comes from assemblies referenced in through the module `Azure.Storage` which is definitely in my list of automation assets.

At the tippy top of my `psm1` file I have

```cs
Using namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File

[DscResource()]
class tAzureStorageFileSync
{
    ...
    # Create the search context
    [CloudFileDirectory] GetBlobRoot()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure whether this `Using` is supported in this scenario or not, so let's call that **Question 1**

To date I have tried:

- Adding `RequiredModules = @( "Azure.Storage" )` to the `psd1` file
- Adding `RequiredAssemblies = @( "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll" )` to the `psd1` file
- Shipping the actual `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` file in the root of the module zip that I upload (that has a terrible smell about it)

When I deploy the module to Azure with `New-AzureRmAutomationModule` it uploads and processes just fine.  The `Extracting activities...` step works and gives no errors.

When I compile a configuration, however, the compilation process fails with the `Unable to find type` error I mentioned.

I have contemplated adding an `Import-Module Azure.Storage` above the `class` declaration, but I've never seen that done anywhere else before.

**Question 2** Is there a way I can compile locally using a similar process to the one used by Azure DSC so I can test changes more quickly?

**Question 3** Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1/3:
If you create classes in powershell and use other classes within, ensure that these classes are present BEFORE loading the scriptfile that contains your new class.

I.e.:
Loader.ps1:

```
Import-Module Azure.Storage
. .\MyDSC-Class.ps1
```

Powershell checks if it finds all types you refer while interpreting the script, so all types must be loaded before that happens. You can do this by creating a scriptfile that loads all dependencies first and loads your script after that.

Comment: Isn't that the whole purpose of the `RequiredModules` field in the psd1?

Comment: Also, the 'using' has to go at the top, so where do I put the `Import-Module`? After the 'using' but before the 'class'? Maybe make a dependent script and wire that into the psd1?

Comment: I think it's more like a error handling thing - but I do not know

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that

Comment: The using statement is only to abbreviate the typenames.

Comment: review this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625440/using-net-objects-within-a-powershell-v5-class

Comment: Yes, true. However the namespace referred to by the 'using' is contained in  an assembly in the module being imported, and it **must** be at the top. So the 'using' precedes the Import, which probably isn't right. I thought the psd1 dependency system was designed to solve this issue. Only it isn't working the way I'd anticipated

Comment: Based on that article, and your lead, I will add the Import-Module into the DSC configuration itself, even though it's only needed in the module. Might be that this adds it into some context somehow. It's clear I can't add it in the class psm1 itself. Perhaps the Config compile process does not properly observe module dependencies? Will give this a go tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 0):

For question 2, if you register your machine as a hybrid worker you'll be able to run the script faster and compile locally. (For more details on hybrid workers, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker/).

If you want an easy way to register the hybrid worker, you can run this script on your local machine (https://github.com/azureautomation/runbooks/blob/master/Utility/ARM/New-OnPremiseHybridWorker.ps1). Just make sure you have WMF 5 installed on your machine beforehand.

Comment: The page at the end of the first link says:
> **Note**:
> Hybrid Runbook Workers do not currently support DSC Configurations

Doesn't this mean I can't actually use it for compiling configurations?

Comment: That note is misleading and will be changed in our documentation. Hybrid runbook workers do not natively support DSC configurations from our service. You must register them as DSC nodes to apply DSC configurations, but you can still use any of the Azure cmdlets to import or compile the DSC configurations.

Answer (score 0):

For authoring DSC configurations and testing locally, I would look at the Azure Automation ISE Add-On available on https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit/0.2.3.6 You can install it by running the below command from an Administrator PowerShell ISE window.
Install-Module AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit -Scope CurrentUser

For loading libraries, I have also noticed that I need to call import-module in order to be able to call methods. I need to do some research to determine the requirement for this. You can see an example I wrote to copy files from Azure Storage using a storage key up on https://github.com/azureautomation/modules/tree/master/cAzureStorage

As you probably don't want to have to deploy the storage library on all nodes, I included the storage library in the sample module above so that it will be automatically distributed to all nodes by the automation service.

Hope this helps,
Eamon

Comment: @EamonOReilly thanks for that - will try out the authoring kit.  I noticed your module but was trying to avoid distributing the dll (which gets out of date) - I assumed the Azure.Storage DSC resource was sufficient, but evidently not.  I have been unable to defeat the parsing error described, so I have removed all references to the types for now.

Comment: Thanks Richard. The reason I wrote this module was so that I had a consistent way to download files to my VM independent if they were in Azure or in the local datacenter. If all of your VMs are in Azure then you could just use the native Azure files SMB capabilities and then access them using the built in File resource and specify the SourcePath as the SMB share.

Comment: Also, the benefit of distributing the dll within the module is that I can control which version gets used. If I want to update the storage library, I can upload a new version of the module and then it will automatically get distributed to all of the nodes by the automation DSC service. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but despite following an article or two I've never been able to get the SMB file share to mount properly, so this is my plan B