# How to Inherit from a .net class in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, class

The following code runs fine when executed in ISE:

```
class MyWindow : Windows.Window {
}
# for testing purposes this is the whole script
```

But when run without ISE it results in an error:

```
At C:\Users\Thelonius\git\ps-scripts\minimal.ps1:1 char:18
+ class MyWindow : Windows.Window {
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [Windows.Window].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

When I run it in a new Powershell window by doing `.\minimal.ps1` the error is the same. After executing `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework` in the shell `.\minimal.ps1` runs without error. Since the error occurs while parsing the script adding the `Add-Type` command to the script is no option. As I understand it instead `using assembly PresentationFramework` should do the job. But it does not (neither in 5.0 nor in 5.1).

So is there a sane way to make it work without loading the assembly by Powershell command-line options or something similarly ugly?

Comment: Seems @PetSerAl is right if there is really no way to do it in a single file. Even using an `.lnk` file with something like `powershell.exe -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework; & .\minimal.ps1"` in it seems way more elegant to me than messing with multiple files.

Comment: This is the entire point of `Add-Type`. Why doesn't it work for you exactly?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Because `Add-Type` is executed at _runtime_, which is too late for the `class` definition to see the type, because it is processed earlier, at _parse time_

Comment: @TNT: Indeed, `using assembly` _should_ do the job, but _doesn't yet_ - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255643/45375

Comment: @mklement0 classes are hoisted?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: You can conceive of it that way, yes: unlike functions, classes have already been parsed by the time execution starts;  try `[Foo]::new().Bar(); class Foo { [string] Bar() { return 'hi' } }`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Add-Type` first in your console:

To get The Assembly path first from ISE:

```
[System.Windows.Window].Assembly
```

Then use `Add-Type` with the location path in the console:

In my System is:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'
```

Then it will work

Comment: This is good information, But, can you suggest a way to get this information from another user's computer?

Comment: I don't get what the advantage is. The error occurs before `Add-Type` is executed.

Comment: @TNT then add it before, at the start of the script file

Comment: I'd suggest just putting `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework` in his script before trying to inherit from it.  You don't need to do all that extra work of finding where the assembly lives.

Comment: @avshalom the problem is that the class has to be defined before the Add-Type. I've ran into this problem in the past and the only solutions I've found is use multiple script files (or create the classes using reflection)