# How to use interfaces in Powershell defined via Add-Type?

Tags: powershell

I developed a PowerShell module that relied on a .NET Assembly for some operations.
I refactored this module to not need that Assembly and noticed some strange behavior, which blocks me from removing the class at last:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "public interface ICanTalk { string talk(); }" -Language CSharp

class Talker : ICanTalk {
    [string] talk() { return "Well hello there"; }
}
```

If you run this commands interactively, it will succeed.
But as soon as I run it "en-bloque" in ISE or from a psm1 file, it will throw an error, stating it cannot find the interface defined in the `Add-Type` call.

I can reproduce the problem in both Windows-PowerShell and PowerShell Core (6.0.2)

What is the reason for the different behaviour and how can I tackle it?

Comment: Don't trust the ISE.

Comment: Probably you are right, but the sample is a minimal reproduction of the problem and it also applies to psm1 files loaded via ipmo.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I can say your test case occurred for me as well in 6.0.3.  It feels like the `Add-Type` command isn't being executed.

Comment: Perhaps classes are parsed before anything else has the chance to execute?

Comment: That sounds familiar.... I think you may be correct.  You'll need to run a script that loads a type before your module gets loaded.  You can specify this in the module manifest.

Comment: [Here's a related issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641)

Comment: Well, that really is the problem. I just made TypeDefinitions.ps1 and Put it into ScriptsToProcess and voila.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .Net Objects within a Powershell (V5) Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625440/using-net-objects-within-a-powershell-v5-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794725/45375):

**PowerShell `class` and `enum` definitions are parsed *before* execution begins** and any **types *referenced* in such definitions** must either be:

- **loaded** into the current session **beforehand**.
- *[**only partially implemented** in *Windows PowerShell* / in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)] *as of v7.3.x*]*
  **loaded via a `using module` / `using assembly` statement** at the very
  top of the file.

  - `using module` already works, but only if the referenced types are *themselves* PowerShell `class` / `enum` definitions.
  - As of PowerShell 7.3.x, **types loaded from .NET *assemblies***  - whether via a module containing assemblies imported with `using module` or `using assembly` to directly load an assembly - **aren't yet detected**.<sup>[1]</sup>

    - See the following GitHub issues:

      - [#3461](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641#issuecomment-297151112) (`using module`) and [#2074](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2074#issuecomment-280191563) (`using assembly`)
      - [#6652](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652) - a meta issue tracking all class-related issues.
  - **Allowing `using assembly` to detect .NET types *at parse time* has been green-lit in [GitHub issue #3641](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641#issuecomment-297151112)**, and the necessary work is being tracked as part of [GitHub issue #6652](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652) - but it is unclear *when* this will happen, given that the issue hasn't received attention in several years.

---

The **workaround** in the meantime is to **load the referenced types via a *separate script* beforehand**, by **using the module manifest's `NestedModules` entry** (which can also be used to dot-source `*.ps1` files).

- Note: The `ScriptsToProcess` entry would work too, but the scripts it references are dot-sourced in (loaded into the current scope of) the *caller*, not the enclosing module.
  With types from *compiled* code (including ad hoc-compiled code with `Add-Type`), that works too, because such types invariably become available session-globally, but it is conceptually cleaner to use `NestedModules`, because it dot-sources scripts in the enclosing *module*'s scope

---

***Outside* of modules**, the **workaround is similar**:

- Put your `class` definition in a *separate `.ps1` file*.
- In your main script, define or load the types that your `class` definition depends on, and *then* [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) the separate script file, which ensures that all its dependent types have already been loaded.
- In a pinch, you can also use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (which [should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637458/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Note that using [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) with `-Assembly` or `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` from inside the script is by definition *not* an option, because `Add-Type` only executes *at runtime* (rather than the `using` statements, which are evaluated at *parse time*), i.e. *too late* to load .NET types available up front. However, calling `Add-Type` from *outside* the target script, *before* the latter is invoked, does work.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Apparently PowerShell will read the file and handle class-definitions before executing the code.

To solve this problem, the `Add-Type` needs to be put into an own script file, which is run before the module loads (or in ISE, just run the code before running the class definitions).

This can be accomplished by using ScriptsToProcess from the PSD1 file.

Kudos to @TheIncorrigible1 for putting me on the track.

Answer (score 0):

Why not defining all classes in C# in a separate file, than add it as
Add-Type -path MyClasses.cs
This way it will work with older PS versions

Comment: The module needs Core 6.0 or Desktop Edition with NET 472 installed, so there's no use in supporting older versions. Also I wanted it to be PS only as far as posdible

Answer (score 0):

If you define -PassThru and bind the Add-Type to a variable, you can use the variable to examine what all is being added.