# The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (PS 5.1)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use [Newtonsoft.Json library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile( 'C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\newtonsoft.json\1.0.2.201\libs\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' )

Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class BigIntegerConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        System.Numerics.BigInteger big = (System.Numerics.BigInteger)reader.Value;
        return new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(big.ToString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
"@
```

and getting the next error:

> The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why it can't find Newtonsoft tho it loaded? I can call it in PS code via [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter], but not in type definitions!

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your `$PsVersionTable` to your question

Comment: `Add-Type` offloads most of its work to an external compiler, so the state of the current application domain doesn't really affect the libraries available to the code you're trying to compile - you probably want `Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"..."@ -ReferencedAssemblies 'path\to\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'`...

Comment: 5.1 ...........

Comment: You're kinda my personal .NET Guardian angel :) This err is fixed, but now it can't found System.Object:  The type 'System.Object' is defined in an
assembly that is not referenced :(

Comment: Honestly, I just need to inherit Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter. But as I understood, I can't inherit directly .NET class from PS. So that I'm trying to do all of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you load the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and `BouncyCastle.Cryptography.dll` assemblies *before* invoking your script - e.g., with `Add-Type -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\newtonsoft.json\1.0.2.201\libs\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'` - **you can define your class *using PowerShell code***, i.e. a ***PowerShell* [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) definition**,  as follows:

```bash
# Note: Assumes that Newtonsoft.Json.dll and BouncyCastle.Cryptography.dll
#       were loaded *before* running this script.
class BigIntegerConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter {
    [bool] CanConvert([Type] $objectType){
        return $objectType -is [Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger]
    }

    [object] ReadJson([Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader] $reader, [Type] $objectType, [object] $existingValue, [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer] $serializer) {
        [bigint] $big = $reader.Value
        return [Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger]::new($big.ToString())
    }

    WriteJson([Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter] $writer, [object] $value, [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer] $serializer) {
        $writer.WriteRawValue($value.ToString())
    }
}
```

The - unfortunate - requirement that any types referenced in a PowerShell [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) have to have been loaded *before* the script at hand is parsed is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813639/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

Mathias is correct in that **you *normally* only need to make sure that the assemblies needed for compiling the C# code passed to [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Type) be passed to `-ReferencedAssemblies`**.

For reasons unknown to me, with `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` specifically, the code below *additionally* requires loading the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` assembly *beforehand* too.

- Note: The **code below** works in ***Windows PowerShell* only** - unlike the *PowerShell* `class` implementation above, which works in *both* editions.

  - However, it ***can* be made to work in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), with extra effort**:

    - Use the *.NET Standard 2.0* implementation of `NewtonSoft.Json.dll` (all implementations are part of the same [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) NuGet package)

      - In the `-ReferencedAssemblies` argument:

        - Add `netstandard`
        - Replace `System.Numerics` with `System.Runtime.Numerics`
      - You then do *not* load `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` beforehand with `Add-Type -LiteralPath`.
    - Alternatively, use the *.NET (Core)* implementation of the assembly:

      - Follow the same steps as above, except for adding `netstandard`
      - Add `-IgnoreWarnings -WarningAction Ignore` to the `Add-Type` call, to ignore and silence warnings regarding a version mismatch between PowerShell's .NET runtime version and the one targeted by `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`
    - If you *accidentally* use a *.NET Framework* implementation, you'll get errors about not finding core types such as `Object`, presumably because they're looked for in .NET Framework assemblies.

```bash
$jsonAssembly = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\newtonsoft.json\1.0.2.201\libs\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
# Specify the path to BouncyCastle.Cryptography.dll here.
$bouncyCastleAssembly = 'C:\path\to\BouncyCastle.Cryptography.dll'

# !! Inexplicably, this is needed too, possibly also for BouncyCastle.Cryptography.dll
Add-Type -LiteralPath $jsonAssembly

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $jsonAssembly, $bouncyCastleAssembly, System.Numerics -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class BigIntegerConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        BigInteger big = (BigInteger)reader.Value;
        return new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(big.ToString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
    }
'@
```

Also note:

- The addition of `using System;` to enable namespace-free references to class `Type`
- The addition of `System.Numerics` to `-ReferencedAssemblies` as well as `using System.Numerics;` to allow namespace-free references to `BigInteger`
- Adding `public` to the `BigInterConverter` class definition to ensure that the resulting class is public.

Comment: Thanks you! Unfortunately, I still have an error: Add-Type : c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\kpspmcfd.0.cs(5) : The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: I suppose System.Object should be in the System namespace, but it seems it doesn't :(

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it, @MegaBomber. I see the "'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced [...]" error only in PowerShell v7+, not in Windows PowerShell - I've updated the answer to make that clear. Seemingly, it looks for .NET Framework rather than .NET (Core) assemblies - not sure why. By contrast, the PowerShell `class` implementation works in both editions.

Comment: @MegaBomber, I've found a way to make it work in PowerShell v7+ too - please see my update. (The "Object" errors stemmed from accidental use of the .NET Framework Newtonsoft assembly)