# Can't stop low level hooks in powershell (c# hook)

Tags: c#, powershell, hook, low-level

after an evening of arguments with both chat gpt and bing chat, I now turn to the (hopefully) wiser people of stackoverflow. My problem is this: I have low level hooks implemented in c#. I subscribe to the events in a powershell class, which I then use in a GUI. Subscribing to the events and starting the hooks works just fine, however, I can't stop the hooks from my class or GUI program. Currently I'm thinking that whenever I press 'f4' the hooks should stop, but I keep getting 'cannot call a method on a null-valued expression', and I really don't understand why it would be null-valued or how I would solve it. Here comes my code, I don't think it's necessary to show the implementation of the hook or the GUI, but let me know otherwise.

```
class InputRecorder {
    [KeyboardHookExample.KeyboardHook] $kh
    [Ikst.MouseHook.MouseHook] $mh
    [System.Windows.Forms.ListView] $list

    InputRecorder() {
        $this.kh = New-Object KeyboardHookExample.KeyboardHook
        $this.mh = New-Object Ikst.MouseHook.MouseHook

        # Store the reference to the class instance
        $self = $this

        # Define the event handler for KeyDown
        $self.kh.add_KeyDown({
            param($sender, $e)
            $vkCode = $sender.vkCode
            Write-Host $vkCode
            if ($vkCode -eq 115) {
                $self.kh.Stop()
                $self.mh.Stop()
            }

            $charCode = [Win32.NativeMethods]::MapVirtualKey($vkCode, 2)
            $char = [char]$charCode

            Write-Host $char
        })

        # Define the event handler for LeftButtonDown
        $self.mh.add_LeftButtonDown({
            param($sender, $e)
            $mousePosition = $sender.pt
            $y = $mousePosition.y
            $x = $mousePosition.x
            $item = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
            $item.ToolTipText = $global:dict["LeftClickCode"] -f $x, $y
            $item.Text = $global:dict["LeftClickDescription"] -f $x, $y
            $CMDList.Items.Add($item)
        })

        # Start the keyboard and mouse hooks
        $self.kh.Start()
        $self.mh.Start()
    }
    [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[string]] getList() {
        return $this.list
    }

    [void] StopHooks() {
        $this.mh.Stop()
        $this.kh.Stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that the **method-local `$self` variable isn't available from inside the script block serving as an event delegate passed to the `.add_KeyDown()` method**.

While it is understandable to expect PowerShell's dynamic [scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) to also apply inside PowerShell's custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)es, that is *not* the case:

A [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) passed as an *event delegate* to a .NET method *from inside a class*:

- does *not* see the local variables of the enclosing *method* - unless you explicitly capture them by calling [`.GetNewClosure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure) on the script block.

  - What it *does* see in the absence of `.GetNewClosure()` are the variables from the *class-defining scope*, i.e. those defined *outside* the class, in the scope in which the class is defined (and from that scope's ancestral scopes), because it runs in a grandchild scope of *that* scope.<sup>[1]</sup>
- does *not* see `$this` as referring to the *instance of the enclosing class*, because - unfortunately - the [automatic `$this` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this) in event delegates *shadows* the `class`-level definition of `$this` and instead refers to the *event sender*.

  - And because class-internal use of `$this` is the only way to gain access to *instance variables* (properties) of a class, the latter are shadowed too.

There are two **solution options**:

- **On a *per-method* basis** (to make your attempt work):

  - Define a method-local variable such as `$self` and then call `.GetNewClosure()` on every event-delegate script block passed to .NET methods *from the same method*, which allows you to access the method-local variables in that script block.
  - However, note that `.GetNewClosure()` will make your script block lose access to the variables from the class-defining scope.
- ***Preferably*, at the *class* level** (no method-specific code needed):

  - Use `(Get-Variable -Scope 1 -ValueOnly this)` to gain access to the the class instance at hand, i.e. to the *shadowed* version of `$this`
  - This obviates the need for method-specific logic and also preserves access to variables from the class-defining scope (if needed).

---

The following **self-contained sample code** demonstrates both approaches:

- For easy visualization, a WinForms form is created (the scoping issues apply equally), with two buttons whose event handlers demonstrate either approach above.
- Clicking either button updates the form's title text with distinct text, and the ability to do so implies that a reference to the enclosing `class` instance was successfully obtained from inside the event-handler script blocks.

**Important:**

- Be sure to execute the following *first*, *before* invoking the code below via a script file:

  ```bash
  Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  ```
- This is - unfortunately - necessary, because (up to at least  PowerShell 7.4.0) any .NET types referenced in a `class` definition must have been loaded into the session *before* the script is parsed (loaded) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813639/45375) for background information.

```bash
# IMPORTANT: 
#  * Run 
#      Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
#    BEFORE invoking this script.

using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

class FormWrapper {
  [Form] $form

  FormWrapper() {
    # Create a form with two buttons that update the form's caption (title text).
    $this.form = [Form] @{ Text = "Sample"; Size = [Size]::new(360, 90); StartPosition = 'CenterScreen' }
    $this.form.Controls.AddRange(@(
        [Button] @{
          Name = 'button1'
          Location = [Point]::new(30, 10); Size = [Size]::new(130, 30)
          Text = "With Get-Variable"
        }
        [Button] @{
          Name = 'button2'
          Location = [Point]::new(190, 10); Size = [Size]::new(130, 30)
          Text = "With GetNewClosure"
        }
      ))

    # Get-Variable approach.
    $this.form.Controls['button1'].add_Click({
        param($sender, [System.EventArgs] $evtArgs)
        # Obtain the shadowed $this variable value to refer to
        # this class instance and access its $form instance variable (property)
        (Get-Variable -Scope 1 -ValueOnly this).form.Text = 'Button clicked (Get-Variable)'
      })

    # Local variable + .GetNewClosure() approach.
    # Define a method-local $self variable to cache the value of $this.
    $self = $this
    # !! YOU MUST CALL .GetNewClosure() on the event-delegate script
    # !! block to capture the local $self variable
    $this.form.Controls['button2'].add_Click({
        param($sender, [System.EventArgs] $evtArgs)
        # Use the captured local $self variable to refer to this class instance.
        $self.form.Text = 'Button clicked (.GetNewClosure)'
      }.GetNewClosure())
  
  }

  ShowDialog() {
    # Display the dialog modally
    $null = $this.form.ShowDialog()
  }

}

# Instantiate the class and show the form.
[FormWrapper]::new().ShowDialog()
```

---

<sup>[1] The immediate parent scope is the class instance at hand, but (a) there appears to be no *method*-level scope (hence no access to method-local variables) and (b) at the instance level the only *variable* that is defined is `$this`, which is *shadowed*, as explained later (and any *instance variables* (properties) must be accessed via `$this.`)</sup>

Comment: Exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Easy to understand and I just love that you provided an example as well. Thank you very much. I went with GetNewClosure and it works like a charm for what I'm trying to accomplish!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @pfeidewigo100; my pleasure. Writing up an example helped me deepen my own understanding.

Comment: A bit of an update (if you are interested). As I said before the solution using GetNewClosure works just fine. However, I've noticed (so far) that whenever I press either space or enter, a new event handler (?) is created. So if I start my hooks, and then press either space or enter, the next event will be recorded twice, and then three times if I press space/enter again. Only these two buttons creates this issue, and they are not even among the keys I actually listen for and perform actions for...

Comment: That is curious, @pfeidewigo100 - I have no explanation. Does it also happen with the `Get-Variable`-based solution?

Comment: It indeed seems very strange. I couldn't get the Get-Variable solution to work so I don't know. It wouldn't find "this" regardless of what scope i chose. I also tried printing all the variables in the scopes, but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: That `Get-Variable` doesn't work is mysterious too. Does it work when you run the sample code in this answer (it does for me)? Is there something special about the hook classes you're using?