# How to get a function to return a Type from a DLL in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dll

I've recently been using powershell to run selenium and I've been trying to group my functions into classes.

I have an overall Selenium class that returns Selenium Objects, for example

```
[OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions]Actions(){
    return New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions($this.selenium)
}
```

The problem I have is that if I try and run the script before I've manually loaded in the DLL's in the console(below), powershell complains it isn't able to find the type.

```
$backed_path = $($directory+"\Selenium_Webdriver_Backed\net"+$netVersion+"\Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll")
$support_path = $($directory+"\Selenium_Webdriver_Support\net"+$netVersion+"\WebDriver.Support.dll")
$core_path = $($directory+"\Selenium_Webdriver\net"+$netVersion+"\WebDriver.dll")

Add-Type -Path $core_path 
Add-Type -Path $backed_path
Add-Type -Path $support_path
```

The Error I get is

```
Unable to find type [OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions].
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Selenium_Automation\Selenium_Wrapper.ps1:41 char:6
+     [OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions]Actions(){
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to load in an external DLL and have a class method return a type from the DLL?

Comment: Well.. If the DLLs are not loaded yet, the error message is obvious. Why not do the `Add-Type` in the classes themselves?

Comment: I do, the error occurs when I do it in the class. The error goes away if I do it in the console first then run the class. I did find this Powershell Issue on Github with the same details as my current problem https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2074

Comment: Ah, yes. I found answers about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625440/using-net-objects-within-a-powershell-v5-class) aswell